# ANTLR dollar sign

Tags: antlr, grammar, dollar-sign

I have been following this guy's tutorial (http://vimeo.com/groups/29150/videos/8137747), and they are great; the only problem is that when I use the "$" sign in my grammar file, like he does, I get an error and my grammar does not compile.

For example I cannot use `($channel = HIDDEN)`.

I followed each instruction of his guide step by step. Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use parenthesis but brackets, and you *should* terminate that statement with a semi-colon. So it's not:

```
($channel = HIDDEN)
```

but:

```
{$channel = HIDDEN;}
```